# What is the SELECT key?

Tags: c#, keyboard, keydown

While searching for some shortcuts for my application, I stumbled over some constants in the C# [Keys enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keys%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

- Select
- Separator
- ProcessKey
- Pa1
- Crsel
- Execute

There's no further information for them on MSDN.
The questions is: which keyboard key corresponds to those values?
(And are they on a standard keyboard layout?)

Comment: MSDN is cool, but have you tried to [Google](https://www.google.com.ua/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=PHqMU5naBo3ANPnzgbAC#q=The+SELECT+key.) it? Gives several nice results for it

Comment: There are some other kind of keyboards instead of standard 102 key keyboard.

Comment: Another question is why do you care? Does it matter if user press *known* key or *unknown*? Your code have to check it anyway. And yes, it's just a key, called `Pa1`.

Comment: @Sinatr: I was searching for a *known* key which is on any keyboard. But I was wondering *where the **** is SELECT* ? Yes - the pressed keys are checked

Comment: If you don't have it, then you .. can't use it, right? =D I don't have `Select` key on my keyboard too, but I have some extra keys (mute, vol+, vol- and sleep) which I am **not** going to use in my software anyway. Because they are not standard. *Reserved* doesn't means *standard*.

Comment: @IlyaIvanov: MSDN is always the *second* one to search. But Google didn't help me much on this...

Comment: @Sinatr: Well my problem is: I don't know if any of the keys I have is *called SELECT* - Like the `Back` key that just has a arrow picture on it.

Comment: None of listed keys are standard. None of them have to be expected to be present on other user keyboard. Don't use them unless you are absolutely sure.

Comment: @Sinatr: You're right, using keys that are not standard isn't a good idea. But I'm still curious - what keyboard layouts have those keys? Some pictures/links?

Comment: Google something like "keyboard 140 keys" =D. [Click](http://www.build-your-own-computer.net/image-files/keyboard-01-ergonomic.jpg).

Comment: Googling "keyboard 140 keys" just results in ads about custom keyboards (in 2022). I posted a researched answer as I was once too curious about the Select key.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`VK_SELECT` is the key code for a <kbd>Select</kbd> key that doesn't exist on most keyboards. I'm pretty sure that I haven't seen one.

You can check to see if your keyboard supports it by calling the [MapVirtualKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646306%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function, which can map the virtual key code to a keyboard scan code. If the function returns 0, then there is no mapping.

I created a little Windows Forms app that illustrates this. Just make a form and hook up a KeyDown handler:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace testoForm
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        [DllImport("user32")]
        static extern UInt32 MapVirtualKey(UInt32 nCode, UInt32 uMapType);
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            ShowKey(e.KeyCode);
        }

        private void ShowKey(Keys key)
        {
            var keyCode = (UInt32)key;
            var scanCode = MapVirtualKey(keyCode, 0);
            var s = String.Format("VK = {0:X2}, SC={1:X2}", keyCode, scanCode);
            MessageBox.Show(s);
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ShowKey(Keys.Select);
        }
    }
}
```

If you press a key, a message box will show the key code and the mapped scan code. I added a button that will show the scan code for the <kbd>Select</kbd> key. On my system, the function returns 0 for `Keys.Select`.

Answer (score 2):

Keys like <kbd>Select</kbd>, <kbd>Attn</kbd>, <kbd>Pa1</kbd>, etc. that can be found from [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/virtual-key-codes) for virtual key codes, are remnants from the early PC era when terminal emulation was still a dominant field of application. For example the [LK201 keyboard](http://xahlee.info/kbd/vt220_terminal.html) used in DEC VT220 terminal and Rainbow 100 computer has a <kbd>Select</kbd> key.

Most prominently however these keys appear on a 122-key IBM [Model F](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_F_keyboard) keyboard for 3270/3179/3180/5250 terminals:
[image: closeup of IBM keyboard]

(image source: [ClickyKeyboards.com](https://www.clickykeyboards.com/product/1985-ibm-model-f-keyboard-6110345-09-sep-85-122-key/))

IBM included support for multiple keyboard types in the original Model 5150 PC specification. Even though the first PC keyboard was the 83-key Model F, other keyboards can be used with an adapter board. In fact, IBM marketed a [3270 PC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_3270_PC) which was a set of expansion boards in a PC XT, making it a fully fledged 3270 terminal.

Further reading:

- https://deskthority.net/wiki/IBM_Model_F
- https://www.rs-online.com/designspark/a-fresh-look-at-ibm-3270-information-display-system

Answer (score 0):

From browsing on the Microsoft forum people say that the SELECT key is the enter key on the keyboard. I found a site that list the keys you're referring to with a very brief explenation of what they are. 
http://cherrytree.at/misc/vk.htm

Comment: Enter is, in ASCII terms, "CR" AKA "Carriage Return", and in MS terms it accordingly is `VK_RETURN` not `VK_SELECT`. I saw some PC extended keyboards that had "return" not "enter" written on the rightmost ("numpad") enter key